# How long does a DynamoDB read/write operation take?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb

Are there public metrics for the distribution of operation timings for simple operations like GetItem and PutItem?

Is it faster to read/write to DynamoDB from within a Lambda function in the same region vs making the request to DynamoDB from a client outside of AWS?

Answer (score 1):

When you provision a DynamoDB table, you can specify the number of Read Capacity Units and the number of Write Capacity Units, which determine the number of reads/writes per second.

See: [Managing Settings on DynamoDB Provisioned Capacity Tables - Amazon DynamoDB](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/ProvisionedThroughput.html)

Accessing DynamoDB will always be faster from an AWS service (eg from an AWS Lambda function or EC2 instance) because the traffic does not need to traverse the Internet.